# Animator set inside the Animator set

Tags: android, animation

```
    var anim = AnimatorSet()

    var anim1 = AnimatorSet()
    anim1.playSequentially(mutablelist)
    anim.play(anim1)

    var anim2 = AnimatorSet()
    anim2.playTogether(mutablelist)
    anim.play(anim2)

    anim.start()
```

Like this I have So many animator inside the Base Animator set.Now My question is ,I want to play the ( anim ) sequentially. But here it runs parallely.Kindly suggest good way to slove this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different way to adding animations to an `AnimatorSet`: either the `AnimatorSet#playTogether(Animator[])` or `AnimatorSet#playSequentially(Animator[])`  this methods can called to add a set of animations all at once, or the `AnimatorSet#play(Animator)` can used in conjunction with methods in the `AnimatorSet.Builder` **class** to add animations one by one.

It is possible to set up `AnimatorSet` with circular dependencies between its animations. For example, an animation a1 could be set up to start before animation a2, a2 before a3, and a3 before a1.

more information about it click [hear](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet#playSequentially(java.util.List%3Candroid.animation.Animator%3E))

Comment: I have a more animatorset[] but i don't know exactly how much. Now want to play all the animatorset one by one.

Comment: animator set stored in list when it comes and then use this methods.